# Unable to locate "fim" package

Tags: software-installation, packages

`sudo apt-get install fim` results in the error message "unable to locate package fim". `fbi` seems to be fine though. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `fim` simply isn't in the Jessie repository. If you like, you can install it manually using the following steps.

1. Download the source code from its [project webpage](http://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/#download).
2. Install some dependencies: `sudo apt-get install -y flex bision libreadline-dev libexif-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libpoppler-dev` These were the libraries I was missing. I already have a lot of development libraries installed, so you may be missing more than this. Feel free to leave a comment if you get an error from this step.
3. Extract the source `tar xfa fim-0.5-trunk.tar.gz`
4. Enter the new directory `cd fim-0.5-trunk`
5. Configure the software by running `./configure`
6. When that's finished, compile the software by running: `make`. Do not use the `-j` option. The Makefile does not appear to be properly configured for it. Note: this will take a long time to run, especially if you're not using an RPi 2.  Grab a cup of coffee or something and be patient.
7. Install the software by running: `sudo make install`
8. Refresh your session. If you're using the default bash shell, this is accomplished by typing `source ~/.bashrc`
9. Enjoy your new software. At this point you can delete the directory you extracted the source files to; you no longer need it.

Comment: `fbi` (Frame buffer viewer) is a current package [fbi 2.10-2+b1_armhf.deb](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/fbi/fbi_2.10-2%2bb1_armhf.deb) and is dated 2015-12-19 at the time of writing.  However `fim` is old [fim_0.3-beta-prerelease-1.3_armhf.deb](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/fim/fim_0.3-beta-prerelease-1.3_armhf.deb) (Scriptable frame buffer and ascii art image viewer) dated 2012-05-10, it is NOT in the Jessie Debian distribution but only in the Wheezy one - as Raspbian is derived from Debian it is not surprising that that package is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a new Fim build dated 2016/01/31.
Compile istructions follow. Successfully built on a Raspbian Jessie as root user.

```
apt-get install -y flex bison libreadline-dev libexif-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libpoppler-dev checkinstall #maybe others on your system.

wget http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/fbi-improved/fim-0.5-rc1.tar.gz
tar -xf fim-0.5-rc1.tar.gz 
cd fim-0.5-rc1 

./configure --disable-readline 
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/doc # Fim will fail creating by itself.
checkinstall
```

Change the Version field in the Checkinstall values page into a numeric one, otherwise it will fail compiling (Checkinstall issue).

Previous commands will compile Fim with framebuffer (built-in) support only and directly create a standard .deb package.

You should add the "non-dev" version of the dev- installed packages as dependencies in the Checkinstall Requires field in order for the .deb to be correctly installed on another Raspbian Jessie.

Notes.

--enable-exiftool flag seems not to work with this upstream release.

Use ./configure --help=short for a complete list of configure options specific to Fim.